# Counting pairs column elements but removing duplicate values

Tags: r, tidyverse

I've got a dataset with event data in the below format

```
> order_df
# A tibble: 10 x 4
       H     M     B    FB
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     0     0
 2     1     1     0     0
 3     1     0     1     0
 4     1     0     0     1
 5     0     1     0     0
 6     0     0     0     0
 7     0     1     1     1
 8     0     0     1     0
 9     0     1     0     0
10     0     0     0     0
```

I'd like to show it as a matrix pairs, which I can achieve with the below code

```
> order_matrix = as.matrix(order_df)
> pair_matrix <- crossprod(order_matrix)
> pair_matrix
   H M B FB
H  4 2 1  1
M  2 5 1  1
B  1 1 3  1
FB 1 1 1  2
```

However, the pair instances (i.e M:M) include all rows from the original dataframe that include that column, but I'd like that value to include only instance where the original dataframe row included ONLY a 1 in the column.

In the example above I'd like the H:H pair to be 0, as all instances with H included another column. the M:M pair would be 1, as only 1 instance included only M

Comment: What's your expected ouput for the sample data frame provided?

Comment: I'd edited to include better examples, and added expected outputs. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about the output here, since if the only rows that are counted are rows with a single 1 in them, then the resulting matrix will only have entries on the diagonal. In other words, it would be better to return a vector than the matrix.

You also say in your question that `M` should be 1, since it only appears on its own once. It actually appears on its own twice (row 5 and row 9).

You can get the result you need by removing all rows with a row sum of more than one then taking the column sums:

```
colSums(as.matrix(order_df[rowSums(order_df) == 1,]))
#>  H  M  B FB 
#>  0  2  1  0
```

and if you check carefully, this is correct.

If you really want the result in a matrix, just remove the rows with more than one value and take the cross product of that:

```
crossprod(as.matrix(order_df[rowSums(order_df) == 1,]))
#>    H M B FB
#> H  0 0 0  0
#> M  0 2 0  0
#> B  0 0 1  0
#> FB 0 0 0  0
```

Comment: So I guess the final output would be `diag(pair_matrix) <- colSums(...)`